# results undefined in querying Mysql Nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I trying to get result query from mysql database in Nodejs, but the 'results.affectedRows' is always 'undefined'. I'm currently using Mac.  I hope you interest for answer my question. Following this my code:

```
const expres = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = expres();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database: "sistemizin"
});
console.log("Connected!");

app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); app.use(expres.static('publik'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('cobaview');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => { 
    var contoh = `SELECT namamatkul FROM matkul_dosen WHERE       idmatkuldosen = 70`;
    connection.query(contoh, (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Results counted:' + results.affectedRows);   
    });
    connection.end();
    res.end();
});

 app.listen(8084);
 console.log("server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8084/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results.affectedRows` is returned only in case of insert, update or delete query. Since yours is a select query, result is as expected.

Comment: I try again with 'result', the return is '[object Object]', how about this?

Comment: You are trying to console log both string and object.. Therefore [object object] since Javascript engine is trying to convert object into string..

TRY console.log(result)... it will do your job..